# TypeScript Builder Pattern similar to Java

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement the Builder Patten similar to Java in TypeScript 4.6.2.
From what I have read, this isn't the preferred way to do it, but I have some constrains regarding the module exports.

```
export class HttpRequest {

    static Builder = class {

        private body: string;

        setBody(body: string): HttpRequest.Builder {
            this.body = body;
            return this;
        }

        build(): HttpRequest {
            return new HttpRequest(this);
        }

    }

    private readonly body: string;

    constructor(builder: any) {
        this.body = builder.body;
    }

    getBody(): string {
        return this.body;
    }

}
```

It seems that the `setBody` method can't return a `HttpRequest.Builder` type, with the following error:

`TS2702: 'HttpRequest' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.`

It seems to work fine if `// @ts-ignore` is present before the method declaration, or if the method signature is changed to `setBody(body: string): any`.

Is there any way to implement this with nested classes? I'm trying to avoid having two different classes, one for `HttpRequest` and one for `Builder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't prefer it to use builder with static classes. You can refer [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAkxgA4CUICOArhAM5gCwAUAN7XKkRj7FlgAUARgPYAmAngC44IfgEpBAN27Be1AL7VqCADZxSpZJhwsS5ZMAC22FREMRwmjFjyE9lWvWQ8BAQkHkooAOYBuJ4zMdmxcfEKePmJ0VMixyAjcIKTcpgB0Ktze7ADkABbc3ADWggxMumzxcCqmvNliTrFgucCkqS78yAC8zmH%20MciKVIPUoJCwiCjWOABCRMAqvNDRsZxzC%20XkoQIeYF4g3hLI0rIKSlSq6pra2LPzi1AGxqbmlmjXtwtLTtheknCQyFyNi6yBAEAA7lobBsOGI%20is1rwYVtwrtIss4gkkikIOlMjl8kUSqs7jDKtUILV6v1Gs1WkCcKlAsj2nCnINhuc1BpkNN1GYLGAMT9gH8AQzsO43jYPvd4fFEp4iAgwNwoOwJYIpjdEdAog1kE0WqkJSCJfLBgi7iidnsDhjYljkmkMlk8gVis5EeSanUDUb6TY2oiWWE2f0OWdTGBAdDCCCwZD3rr1eHo167tAExDefyXhwJSxw9R0%200QQAiYDIOCGHpuct9EmfKDB62s3xAA) to access a playground template.

If you want to achieve it in your way do this:

```
class HttpRequest {

    static Builder = class {

        public body!: string;

        setBody(body: string): typeof HttpRequest.Builder {
            this.body = body;
            return this as any;
        }

        build(): HttpRequest {
            return new HttpRequest(this);
        }

    }

    private readonly body: string;

    constructor(builder: any) {
        this.body = builder.body;
    }

    getBody(): string {
        return this.body;
    }

}
```

But instead you can practice full pattern with:

```
interface IHttpRequest
{
 setRequest(body:any):void
}

class HttpRequest implements IHttpRequest
{
  body!:string;
  setRequest(body:string){
    console.log('hook: setRequest called')
    this.body = body;
  }
}

interface IHttpBuilder{
  buildRequest(body:string): void
}

class HttpBuilder implements IHttpBuilder{
  private http = new HttpRequest();
  buildRequest(body:string){
    console.log('hook: buildRequest called')
    this.http.setRequest(body);
  }
}

class Basement{
  private http!: IHttpBuilder;
  constructor(http:IHttpBuilder){
    this.http = http;
  }
  build(body:string){
    console.log('hook: build called')
    this.http.buildRequest(body);
  }
}

let httpReq = new HttpBuilder();
let builder = new Basement(httpReq);

let body = "i am body!";
builder.build(body);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience using a fluent API has served me best when writing typescript builders, here's how I would do it in more of a typescript way.

```
interface HttpRequest {
    body: string;
}

export class HttpRequestBuilder {
    private body: string = "";

    public withBody(newBody: string): HttpRequestBuilder {
        this.body = newBody;
        return this;
    }

    public build(): HttpRequest {
        return {
            body: this.body
        }
    } 
}
```

Then to use this you can just new up the class

```
const httpRequest = new HttpRequestBuilder()
    .withBody("add a body here")
    .build();
```

This pattern also has several other options to be extended further.

Update: here is a hypothetical example extension to give you even more versatility.

```
export interface HttpRequest {
    body: string;
    contentType: string;
}

export interface HttpRequestExtension extends HttpRequest {
    message: string;
}

export class HttpRequestBuilder {
    private body: string = "";
    private contentType: string = "";

    public withBody(newBody: string): HttpRequestBuilder {
        this.body = newBody;
        return this;
    }

    public withContentType(newContentType: string): HttpRequestBuilder {
        this.contentType = newContentType;
        return this;
    }

    public build(): HttpRequest {
        return {
            body: this.body,
            contentType: this.contentType
        }
    } 
}

export class HttpRequestExtensionBuilder extends HttpRequestBuilder {
    private message: string = "";

    public withMessage(newMessage: string): HttpRequestExtensionBuilder {
        this.message = newMessage;
        return this;
    }

    public build(): HttpRequestExtension {
        return {
            ...super.build(),
            message: this.message
        }
    }
}
```

This way we can use either builder:

```
const httpRequest = new HttpRequestBuilder()
    .withBody("add a body here")
    .withContentType("text/html")
    .build();

const httpRequest = new HttpRequestExtensionBuilder()
    .withMessage("add a message here")
    .withBody("add a body here")
    .withContentType("text/html")
    .build();
```